# Installing ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET and what else to be able to display offline maps?

Tags: software-recommendations, offline, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

We have WPF application that is intended to run on Windows laptops carried in the field, that includes some mapping functionality. We need to be able to provide some mapping functionality, even when the laptops are offline.

With respect to mapping, our customers fall into three groups:

1. Customers who are heavy ESRI customers, who have defined their own maps using ESRI's software. For these, we expect we'll be able to display the maps in the application using ESRI's ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF.
2. Customers who aren't ESRI customers, but who have their own facility layers defined that they want to be able to load on the laptop and display in the application.
3. Customers who don't have their own facility layers defined, but need to be able to display streetmaps.

We know we can use ESRI's ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF for the first group of customers.

What we don't know is whether we can use the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for the second and third groups.

What we need for the second group is the ability for the customer to copy their map data onto their laptops, in some standard format, so that we can display their map data within the application.

What we need for the third group is to load a standard landbase onto their laptops so that we can display a street map within the application.

Looking at the ESRI documentation, it looks as if the Basic level would suffice for the second and third groups: [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET - License your app][1].

But it's not clear to me what is involved in deploying an app.

With the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET, what needs to be installed on the laptop, besides the application itself, to be able to display offline maps?  [1]: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/license-your-app.htm

Comment: Have you looked into the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/ArcGIS_Runtime_SDK_for_WPF/017000000031000000/)?  It supports offline editing.

Comment: What sort of maps? are they just base maps to guide data collection, or is it for navigation? what size of maps? what region?

Comment: Does it have to be ESRI based?

Comment: For customer group 1, it has to be ESRI, for groups 2&3, it doesn't have to be, but it would be less work to use ESRI for everybody.

Comment: Collector for ArcGIS (Windows version) https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/windows/collect-data/offline-use.htm with offline editing